# Is there an operation Step Back in NetBeans during debug process?

Tags: debugging, netbeans

In NetBeans when you insert *Breakpoint* and *Debug project*, it runs code until the *Breakpoint* and stop right in a line where we put *Breakpoint*. And afterwards we can execute our code step by step. If we Press <kbd>F8</kbd> which is *Step Over* operation, NetBeans executes next line. Sometimes we want to go back to the previous executed line because we want to change that line and see how it will work. 
So, the question is how can I say NetBeans to **Step Back** (if we can call this like this), so instead of executing next line code it executes previous line code? I remember in Visual Basic 6.0 (now I don't know because don' t use it anymore) we could manage current execution line, i.e. we could just drag and drop debug pointer to the line we want during the debugging and it would start to execute code right from the place we put it. Is it possible in NetBeans?

**Update 1**
I use NetBeans for debugging PHP application. PHP uses `php_xdebug-2.1.0RC1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll`  to to debug PHP code.

Comment: For the curious, there is a reverse debugger for PHP since come time. https://github.com/sidkshatriya/dontbug

Answer (score 3):

I think he was referring to the pop top most call stack.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqDebugBackup

Answer (score 1):

It's not only a matter of Netbeans (or to say it more generally: your IDE), it's also a matter of the debug capabilities of your jvm.
AFAIK, no jvm does currently have this feature.

What might be possible (in Eclipse it is) is to step to the beginning of the method, but you have to be careful about the state of your objects, because you may reach a state which you won't within a normal execution.